# ControlChannelTrigger Background Task in Universal Windows Apps and StreamMessageWebSocket

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

I am trying to use a following example but I have migrated it to UWP: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ControlChannelTrigger-91f6bed8
Everything works perfectly except that it doesn't work for Windows Mobile. When I deploy it to Windows 10 desktop everything is fine but when I deploy it to phone I get the following exception: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072F75. Please advise, I'm having this issue for the last one year.
Exactly in this place:

```
            await socket.ConnectAsync(serverUriInstance);
```

Comment: Please refer to [ControlChannelTrigger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701032), the "Note" in this document says: This class is not supported on Windows Phone.

Comment: But this is not a Windows Phone anymore - it's Windows 10 for Mobile. Should I treat Windows Phone in this case as Windows 10 on mobile systems?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm migrating the sample to UWP now and trying to reproduce your problem, I'll let you know if there is new progress.

Comment: Thank you very much for that - it's very important for me and I've been trying to do that for a year and ended up creating the server which gets data from websocket and send using WNS but this is not the best solution

Comment: I am afraid to say that Control Channel Trigger is still not supported on phones. WNS is the way to go.

Comment: @kiewic there is no workaround for it? Are you planning to fix this?